# UICollectionView Cell not loading

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell in which I am trying to display a label with some text. I have added the label as a subview of the cell's contentView. But the label only loads on the first cell, and when I scroll, some load and some don't. Why are all the cells not loading? I have tried adding `cell.contentView.setNeedsDisplay()` and `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` before the return cell but none of them work.

Comment: is your data first comes from webservice or you have static data?

Answer (score 0):

you may check few things:

- Is your auto-layout done correctly? provide a fixed width and height to your label and add a red background color for example if it is ok then go to next point
- maybe the data is not ready for display try to put hardcoded text to your cell label if it works
- then you may load data before showing your view and in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Check you constraints on collection view.

And also make sure you have set these also
UICollectionViewDataSource
UICollectionViewDelegate
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout